# functionality of function ord()

Tags: python, string, ord

can anyone explain what the function ord does in this code?
The code is meant to multiply the numbers written as strings (without using int()).

```
def multiply(num1, num2):
    """
    :type num1: str
    :type num2: str
    :rtype: str
    """

    res1, res2 = 0, 0 
    for d in num1:
        print(d)
        print(ord(d))
        print(ord('0'))
        res1 = res1 * 10 + (ord(d) - ord('0'))
    for d in num2:
        res2 = res2 * 10 + (ord(d) - ord('0'))
    return str(res1 * res2)
```

How can ord(d) - ord('0') finally return the correct result. I don't understand what exactly ord does.

Is ord('0') always 48 (which is what I get when I print)?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `ord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) is a function that takes a character and returns the number that unicode associates that character with. The way unicode structures the digits 0-9 `ord("9")-ord("0")` will result in `9`. `ord` of 0 is 48 and the digits count up from there: "1" is 49, "2" is 50 etc. That code removes the offset of the digits in unicode so that you get the number that the digit is in order. So `ord("2") - ord("0")` evaluates to `50 - 48` which is `2`.

The inverse of `ord` is `chr` which will return the character given a number. `chr(48)` is `"0"` You can play around with these functions as well as looking at an [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (which is contained in unicode) to learn more about how characters are represented in computers.

Answer (score 0):

returns an integer representing the **Unicode code** point of the character